# compare times in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have array of time data in format `HH:mm` like `13:58`. Let's say that array has 50 entries with different times. How can I compare new time for example `18:29` is it bigger than any inside array? Should I convert each time into seconds or is there better approach?

Comment: If you encode values as, e.g., `01:02` a String comparison should work fine (although conversion to seconds would be preferable from my point of view).

Comment: Yes converting it to seconds would be better since you would not need to do the calculation on every iteration. Array `some` is probably what you want to use.

Comment: Conversion to seconds is always preferrable, since comparing strings will give you bugs if you forget leading zeroes. `"2" < "10" --> false`

Comment: Do you care about timezones?

Answer (score 1):

You can use momentjs:

```
var time1 = "18:58";
var time2 = "20:30";

var isBefore = moment(time1, "HH:mm").isBefore(moment(time2, "HH:mm"));
console.log(isBefore);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a comparator function. All you need to do is pass the hour and minutes into a Date constructor and get the milliseconds.

```js
function toIntArray(arr) {
  return arr.map(function(x) { return parseInt(x, 10) });
}
function timeToMillisecondsUTC(time) {
  var tokens = toIntArray(time.split(':'));
  return Date.UTC(1970, 0, 1, tokens[0], tokens[1]);
}
function timeCompare(a, b) {
  return timeToMillisecondsUTC(a) - timeToMillisecondsUTC(b);
}

var dateStrings = [ '13:58', '18:29', '15:25', '12:01' ];

console.log(dateStrings.sort(timeCompare));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that uses regexps and `String.replace` to convert the time to a number of minutes, so it can be easily compared.

The uses the `Array.every` method to check if every entry of a list returns true from the predicate function

```js
let convert = s => s.replace(/(\d+):(\d+)/, (match, $1, $2) => $1*60 + $2*1);
let list = ["11:25", "10:38"];
let out = list.every(entry => convert(entry) > convert("18:29"));

console.log(out)
```

Comment: just the arrow function might need to be transpiled for older browser, and you can easily switch that for a regular function